# Determining $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ s.t. there is $X \subseteq [0,1]$ s.t. $\mu (X \cap (a,b)) = f(b-a)$ for all $(a,b) \subset [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is which functions $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ satisfy that there is measurable $X$ such that for all intervals $(a,b) \subset [0,1]$, ($a \leq b$) we have that the measure of $X \cap (a,b)$ is $f(b-a)$. I believe that the answer is only $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be such a function. 
From $$f(nx)=\mu(X\cap [0,nx))=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(X\cap [(i-1)x,ix)) =\sum_{i=1}^n f(x)=nf(x)$$
for $0\le x\le\frac1n$, we conclude that 
$$ \frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}f(1)=\lfloor nx\rfloor f(\tfrac1n)\le f(x)\le \lceil nx\rceil f(\tfrac1n)=\frac{\lceil nx\rceil}{n}f(1).$$
As we let $n\to\infty$, we find $f(x)=xf(1)$ and hence $\mu(X\cap[a,b])=f(1)(b-a)$ for all $0\le a\le b\le 1$.

Assume $f(1)\ne0$. Then for a measureable set $E\subseteq \mathbb R$ we can define
$$\tilde \mu(E)=\frac1{f(1)}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mu(X\cap (E-n)).$$
Observe that $\tilde\mu$  is a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with $\tilde\mu((a,b])=b-a$ for all $a<b$, hence is the Lebesgue measure.
Hence $$1-f(1)=\mu([0,1]\setminus X)=\tilde\mu([0,1]\setminus X)=\frac1{f(1)}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mu(\emptyset)=0. $$

We conclude that $f(1)\in\{0,1\}$ and so $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ are the only possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was correct. =) The first step I thought of was to show $f$ was additive and continuous, hence linear by theorem, but your first step is even more elementary than that.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the second part of the proof, but I am pondering it. Do you take the sum over $n$ essentially just to extend the measure to the entire line?